# Count chars in JtextPane without space

Tags: java, string

I build a simple notepad. It has to count chars without space and "\n".

When I use space in program it does not count " ", but after when I write chars the program count this and the space.

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    a.setText("Counts  :" + c.getText().trim().length());
    b.setText("Words :");
}
```

Comment: use `String.replace` to remove thiese characters

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all the `spaces` and then check the `length`

```
a.setText("Counts  :" + c.getText().replace(" ", "").length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll()` which can accept to use a regex, for example :

```
a.setText("Counts  :" + c.replaceAll("\\s*\\n*", "").length());
```

**Input**

```
simple text \n simple text         \n
```

**Output**

```
text   = "simpletextsimpletext"
length = 20
```